# Python - lists functions within functions for handling list not working

Tags: python, list, function, sorting, math

This program runs successfully.
The first function is taking a list and the number of items in the list as parameters. It returns a list.
The second function calls the first function. Runs it. Appends the data to list4 and sorts it.
But, why does the sort not sort the list4 ?

```
def trysumlist(list2,x):
    for i in range(0, x):
        num = input(f'Enter a number: ')
        num = int(num)
        list2.append(num)
    print(list2)       #Prints the values of the list
    return list2       #Prints the values of the list
functionlist = []     #without defining function list, it was giving error. Always initialize
print(trysumlist(functionlist,3))

def sortmylist():
    list4=[]
    list3 = []
    trysumlist(list3,4)
    print(f'in list 3 : {list3}')
    list4.append(list3)
    print(f'in list4 : {list4}')
    #list4.sort()
    list4.sort()
    print(f'sorted list : {list4}')
    return list4
print(sortmylist())
```

Comment: the list4 is a list of list. do want to sort the elements of the list3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to keep the list4 as list of list or a list.

if you want list4 is going to be a list of list and you can plan to sort the each list within it and its better to sort it before adding it in list4.

```
list3.sort()
list4.append(list3)
```

if you want to keep to the list4 as a list then use `extend` instead of `append`. In this case the sort would work.

```
list4.extend(list3)
list4.sort()
```

Example using extend instead of append.

```
In [29]: def trysumlist(list2,x): 
    ...:     for i in range(0, x): 
    ...:         num = input(f'Enter a number: ') 
    ...:         num = int(num) 
    ...:         list2.append(num) 
    ...:     print(list2)       #Prints the values of the list 
    ...:     return list2       #Prints the values of the list 
    ...: #functionlist = []     #without defining function list, it was giving error. Always 
    ...: initialize 
    ...: #print(trysumlist(functionlist,3)) 
    ...:  
    ...: def sortmylist(): 
    ...:     list4=[] 
    ...:     list3 = [] 
    ...:     trysumlist(list3,4) 
    ...:     print(f'in list 3 : {list3}') 
    ...:     list4.extend(list3) 
    ...:     print(f'in list4 : {list4}') 
    ...:     #list4.sort() 
    ...:     list4.sort() 
    ...:     print(f'sorted list : {list4}') 
    ...:     return list4 
    ...: print(sortmylist())                                                                 
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 4
[3, 1, 5, 4]
in list 3 : [3, 1, 5, 4]
in list4 : [3, 1, 5, 4]
sorted list : [1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `extend()` method for adding elements of `list3` to `list4` — append adds the entire list as one element (list in list)